# angular js directive to replace ng-src on img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Currently I have an image tag in which I need to do a JavaScript replace on. was looking online and I've read some peoples thoughts about using a directive to achieve this but haven't found an example that could help me.

My current setup looks like this:

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{day.Item.Logo}}" item-logo>
```

day.Item.Logo is just a string being returend that looks something like this.

```
http://domainnamehere.com/image%s%s.png
```

And my directive as it currently stands.

```
    myApp.directive("itemLogo", function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
           attrs.ngSrc = attrs.ngSrc.replace("%s", "24");
           attrs.ngSrc = attrs.ngSrc.replace("%s", "24");
        }
    });
```

I know I am obviously doing something wrong in the directive I believe but I dont know for sure. Essentially i'd like to replace both "%s" with "24" and return it back to the view before it makes the request to fetch/load the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in order of directive  processing by angular. When it compiles your directive, ng-src might already has been processed. I would modify the url in the controller just before putting it to the model.

Another way is to put a function call to ng-src which modifies the url.

```
ng-src='{{formatUrl(day.Item.Logo)}}'
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qucobi/2/edit?html,js,output)